# Boundary terms of action in AdS

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, metric-tensor, action, ads-cft, boundary-terms

Let's consider the action of a free scalar field in a space-time with metric $g_{\mu \nu}$

$$ S = -\frac{\eta}{2} \int d^{d+1}x \, \sqrt{g} \{g^{AB} \partial_{A} \phi \partial_{B} \phi + \frac{1}{2} m^2 \phi^2 \}, $$

where $g = |det(g)|$.

Integration by parts and Stokes theorem allows us to rewrite the integral as

$$ S = -\frac{\eta}{2} \int_{\partial M} dS_{A} \,  \sqrt{g}g^{AB}  \phi \partial_{B} \phi + \frac{\eta}{2} \int d^{d+1}x \, \{ \phi \, \partial_A (\sqrt{g}g^{AB}  \partial_{B} \phi)+ \frac{1}{2} m^2 \phi^2 \}, $$

In the case of Minkowski metric, one assumes that the fields vanish on the asymptotic boundary, which lets us drop the first term.

Is this also the case in AdS? And if not, what implications does it have?

I am in the process of learning AdS/CFT and would specifically be interested in answers relating to it.